# How to add a full screen button in a media player video

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm creating a listView of videos and I need this button which fills the video screen, so I implement this MediaElement:

```xml
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"

 <xct:MediaElement Grid.Row="0"
        Aspect="AspectFill"
        HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=170,
                                Tablet=170,
                                Desktop=170}"
        WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=343,
                               Tablet=343,
                               Desktop=423}"
        Source="urllllllllllllllllllll" 
        AutoPlay="True" Background="transparent" IsTabStop="True" ShowsPlaybackControls="True"/>
```

And this is the result:
[image]
But I need to add a full screen icon button and make it work.

Comment: You want the entire MediaElement control to be squished into the upper left corner?

Comment: No I only need that button the position of it doesn't matter

Comment: I have no idea what "that button" is.  There is no button in your XAML.

Comment: @jason the icon button wich display te video in full screen I want to know how can I add it and make it work in

Comment: @jason yes I haven't aany button in the xaml because I don't know how to implement it

Comment: AFAIK MediaElement doesn't have any ability to switch to full screen mode.  Usually that is a function of the OS.

Comment: @Jason do you have any suggestion to have a similar functionality ?

Comment: As I know, `MediaElement` does not support full screen.  For now, we are no longer adding new features to Xamarin Community Toolkit, focusing on the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit. https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/650 You could post your new request on the GitHub issue of Maui. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have implemented grid. You can achieve your result by placing both the button and the current media player into the grid.

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


               <xct:MediaElement Grid.Row="0"
                     Aspect="AspectFill"
                     HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=170,
                     Tablet=170,
                     Desktop=170}"
                     WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=343,
                           Tablet=343,
                           Desktop=423}"
                    Source="urllllllllllllllllllll" 
                    AutoPlay="True" Background="transparent" IsTabStop="True" ShowsPlaybackControls="True"/>

                <ImageButton
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Source="iconfullscreen.png"
                    VerticalOptions="Start" />
            </Grid>
```

You can find Demonstration & project [here](https://github.com/Tuurash/MediaElementModified)